# /usr/bin/find Argument list too long

Tags: linux, shell, find, redhat, xargs

Trying to search for all files that are excluded from list.txt using the following from the command line

```
find . -type f -name "*.ext" $(printf "! -name %s " $(cat list.txt))
```

I get the following result

```
-bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
```

I have also tried with xargs but not sure if I am using it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried with `xargs`?

Comment: Obvious question would be how big your list is - if you chop off just the first 10 lines does it work then, or is there something wrong with the idea in concept as well as quantity?  Also, you might try preceding the command line with `echo` to sort of produce a "what it might do" output.

Comment: The list has over 1M lines

Comment: I tried just piping to xargs by adding -print0 | xargs -0

Comment: replace "*.ext" with '*.ext' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pipe to `grep`:

```
find -type f -name '*.ext' | grep -vFf list.txt
```

When passing `-f` grep reads search patterns from a file. `-v` negates the search. Usually `grep` treats search patterns as regular expressions. If you `-F` `grep` will treat those as fixed strings.

Comment: This makes sense, but I got the following output ------------------------- "grep: Unmatched [ or [^"

Comment: What if you try `find ... | grep -vFf list.txt` ?

Comment: Yes! This works! The -vFf helped to deal with the whitespace I assume. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

> find . -type f -name "*.ext" -exec grep -v "^{}$" list.txt && echo {}
>   \;

Comment: got the following : find: missing argument to `-exec'

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're aiming to do with your command, so these remarks are a little generic.

If you want to grep a large number of files for the word `foo`, for example, then you'd do something like

```
find . -type f -name \*.ext | xargs grep foo
```

The important thing here is that the `\*` is passed to `find` for it to expand, and it is *not* expanded by the shell.  The 'Argument list too long' error is probably the result of the *shell* expanding your `"*.ext"` and trying to pass that long list as a bunch of arguments to find.  This may be the key thing you're missing in your experiments here.

The way that `xargs` works is that it reads arguments from the stdin (in this case the list of files produced by `find`), and calls the given function repeatedly with as many of these arguments as will fit.  If the strings being sent to `xargs` are at all unusual, you should look at the `-0` option for `xargs`.

Another way to use find, which is more natural in some circumstances, is

```
find . -type f <whatever> | while read f; do some-command $f; done
```

Here, `while` again reads lines one at a time, assigning them in turn to `f`, which are processed one at a time in the loop.

Comment: How would this exclude the files from list.txt?

Comment: @biggthed Ahhh, I _see_ what you're doing with `list.txt`! (doh: the bit I was focusing on was the argument-number overflow that might result from `"*.ext"`)  The way I'd do that is not by constructing a mega argument list for `find`, but by `find . -name \*.ext | cat - list.txt | sort | uniq -u | ...`.  The `cat - list.txt` results in a list where all the files in `list.txt` are duplicated, which are duly removed by `uniq -u`